# How can I find all the posts marked as community-wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki, search

How can I find all the posts marked as community-wiki ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3Ayes

So include `wiki:yes` as part of your search, to get all posts with a wiki status.

Note: You can find this information (and more) by clicking on the "Advanced Search Tips" link next to the search box on [the search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for the respective site.